# COOCA: How to know what functions are provided by a dylib on mac?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

`libz.dylib` is used for compression and decompression, so I added it to my project under Link Binary with Libraries section of Build Phase tab. But I do not see any header file inside it to know the functionality provided by `libz.dylib`so how to use it, what function it provides?

In case of framework we can see method declaration in .h files and based on that we can use appropriate function so how one can get info about a dylib.

My question is not specific to `libz.dylib` it is for general dylib. I have gone through some tutorial for sqllite also all says to add `libsqlite3.0.dylib` but none specify why to add and what functionality it provides.Also I didn't find any documentation of particular dylib.

Comment: You need a disassembler. You can try http://www.hopperapp.com/ or use lldb (or gdb) to set a breakpoint on the dylib and figure out which function are called from there. See http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the header in the SDK under /usr/include/zlib.h (e.g. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/zlib.h).

There's also a [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/zlib.3.html).

The home page for the zlib project is [here](http://www.zlib.net/) and the manual is [here](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html).